# Can't install Linux Mint after Windows 11

Tags: boot, linux-mint, windows-11, dualboot

After performing a clean install of Windows 11 on my PC, I have tried to install Linux Mint (Cinnamon 20.3) in order to have dual boot Windows/Linux. I burned the Linux iso image onto a USB and tried to boot from it. However, after selecting the option to install Linux Mint, I get the error **"Firmware error: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer"** and the screen glitches (overlapped text appears and lines of different colors).

Before installing Windows 11, I changed my BIOS options in order to allow the installation: I **enabled TPM 2.0, disabled CSM and enabled secure boot** (Windows UEFI Mode). However, I think that those options are interfering with the Linux Mint installer. From what I've read, I believe the secure boot option does not allow the execution of the Linux Mint installer.

So the question is: is Linux Mint compatible with all the new security options introduced by Windows 11 (TPM 2.0 and secure boot)? If so, what do I need to do in order to install Linux Mint alongside Windows 11? If not, is it okay to disable the secure boot and/or tpm options? Will it harm my experience (i.e., security, updates, etc.) with Windows 11?

Below some additional data:

Motherboard: ASUS TUF Gaming B450-PLUS

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X

[How I burned the ISO onto the USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsDCj.png)

Comment: Mint supports both TPM and Secure Boot it has for years.

Comment: I suggest not butchering Windows 11 to make dual boot work. People waste MOUNTAINS of time trying to set up dual boot. Use a Virtual Machine instead for Mint and save yourself MUCH hassle and MUCH time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem.

It seems the issue was not with dual boot+TPM. When I burned the Linux ISO image onto the USB, I changed from MBR to GPT (I don't know if this is important for my issue or not), and was able to install Linux Mint in **compatibility mode**.

After installing it, the necessary keys were added to the UEFI (to allow secure boot) via the MOK tool (I think this is what this tool is for) and, from that moment, I have been able to boot both Windows and Linux Mint (in normal mode) using grub. Whenever I boot Linux, the firmware error still appears but the system is able to boot nonetheless (instead of freezing).

In conclusion, as pointed out by @Ramhound, **it is possible to boot Linux Mint with secure boot + TPM 2.0 enabled.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).